# UTC to Eastern Converter - Looping through list in a function

Tags: python, time, twitter, utc

I have a csv of tweets with the column "created_at" that shows times in UTC as such:

Thu Mar 19 12:37:15 +0000 2015

I created this function so that is can convert a UTC time to Eastern time (EST or EDT):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('tweets.csv')

from datetime import datetime
from email.utils import parsedate_tz, mktime_tz
import pytz

def to_local_time(tweet_time_string):
    timestamp = mktime_tz(parsedate_tz(tweet_time_string))
    dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp, pytz.timezone('US/Eastern'))
    return dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

time_string = to_local_time('Thu Mar 19 12:37:15 +0000 2015')
```

But I want to loop it through the entire column of df['created_at'] as opposed to inputting a single value one by one like above. I tried:

```
import numpy as np
time = df['created_at']

for row in time:
    new_time = to_local_time(time)
    print(np.array(new_time))
```

But get the error ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

How can I iterate through the entire "created_at" column to convert all values from UTC to Eastern and save the new Eastern time as a new column in the dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

Try [.tz_convert('US/Eastern')](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.tz_convert.html)

```
# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['Thu Mar 19 12:37:15 +0000 2015']})
# convert to datetime and convert utc to Eastern
df['Date_Eastern'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.tz_convert('US/Eastern')

                                 Date              Date_Eastern
    0  Thu Mar 19 12:37:15 +0000 2015 2015-03-19 08:37:15-04:00
```

## larger sample data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.date_range('2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', freq='h')})
df['Eastern'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], utc=True).dt.tz_convert('US/Eastern')

                  Date                   Eastern
0  2023-01-01 00:00:00 2022-12-31 19:00:00-05:00
1  2023-01-01 01:00:00 2022-12-31 20:00:00-05:00
2  2023-01-01 02:00:00 2022-12-31 21:00:00-05:00
3  2023-01-01 03:00:00 2022-12-31 22:00:00-05:00
4  2023-01-01 04:00:00 2022-12-31 23:00:00-05:00
5  2023-01-01 05:00:00 2023-01-01 00:00:00-05:00
6  2023-01-01 06:00:00 2023-01-01 01:00:00-05:00
7  2023-01-01 07:00:00 2023-01-01 02:00:00-05:00
8  2023-01-01 08:00:00 2023-01-01 03:00:00-05:00
9  2023-01-01 09:00:00 2023-01-01 04:00:00-05:00
10 2023-01-01 10:00:00 2023-01-01 05:00:00-05:00
11 2023-01-01 11:00:00 2023-01-01 06:00:00-05:00
12 2023-01-01 12:00:00 2023-01-01 07:00:00-05:00
13 2023-01-01 13:00:00 2023-01-01 08:00:00-05:00
14 2023-01-01 14:00:00 2023-01-01 09:00:00-05:00
15 2023-01-01 15:00:00 2023-01-01 10:00:00-05:00
16 2023-01-01 16:00:00 2023-01-01 11:00:00-05:00
17 2023-01-01 17:00:00 2023-01-01 12:00:00-05:00
18 2023-01-01 18:00:00 2023-01-01 13:00:00-05:00
19 2023-01-01 19:00:00 2023-01-01 14:00:00-05:00
20 2023-01-01 20:00:00 2023-01-01 15:00:00-05:00
21 2023-01-01 21:00:00 2023-01-01 16:00:00-05:00
22 2023-01-01 22:00:00 2023-01-01 17:00:00-05:00
23 2023-01-01 23:00:00 2023-01-01 18:00:00-05:00
24 2023-01-02 00:00:00 2023-01-01 19:00:00-05:00
```

Comment: This is also for one date. How can I get this for every row in my date column?

Comment: It will work for all rows. You do not need a loop.

Comment: How does it work for all rows?

Comment: That is how this pandas function works. Did you click on the link I provided or try it on your actual data?

Comment: Thank you, from your reference I was able to do it!

Answer (score 0):

Update:

Final code for how to do what I asked -

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('tweets.csv')

time = df['created_at']
time = np.asarray(time)

# sample data
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': time})

# convert to datetime and convert utc to Eastern
df['Date_Eastern'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date']).dt.tz_convert('US/Eastern')
```

Comment: This is a minor issue. the pandas Series is a one-dimensional array. You don't have to convert it to a numpy array, and then create a new pandas DataFrame.